# set div mouse coordinates within scaled div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Problem is:
I´ve a transformed div like this:

```
$('#container').css('-moz-transform-origin', '0 0'); 
$('#container').css('-webkit-transform-origin', '0 0');
$('#container').css('-o-transform-origin', '0 0');
$('#container').css('-ms-transform-origin', '0 0');
$('#container').css('-transform-origin', '0 0');

$('#container').css('-moz-transform', 'scale(.5)');
$('#container').css('-webkit-transform', 'scale(.5)');
$('#container').css('-o-transform', 'scale(.5)');
$('#container').css('-ms-transform', 'scale(.5)');
```

now i append another div to this scaled container...

```
id('container').appendChild( follower );
```

if I know want to set this div exactly to document´s mouse position...
follower´s position differs extremly from documents mouse position

```
$( document ).mousemove( function( e ) {

var IE = document.all ? true : false;

if ( IE ) {
   vx = e.clientX;
   vy = e.clientY;      
} else {
   vx = e.pageX;
   vy = e.pageY;
} 

follower.style.left = xDropPos + 'px';
follower.style.top  = yDropPos + 'px';
}
```

how to fix this?

Comment: post http://jsfiddle.net

Comment: here´s the problem as jsfiddle jsfiddle.net/__pwd__/9fVKH

Answer (score 0):

Use `vx` and `vy` parameters like,

```
$( document ).mousemove( function( e ) {
    var IE = document.all ? true : false;
    if ( IE ) {
       vx = e.clientX;
       vy = e.clientY;      
    } else {
       vx = e.pageX;
       vy = e.pageY;
    } 
    follower.style.left = vx + 'px';// use vx
    follower.style.top  = vy + 'px';// use vy
});
```

Comment: ...but still when adding the vx * scale and vy * scale the div´s in another position

Comment: if you move the mouse over the rescaled square and want to set the red square to the mouse coordinates - it fails... http://jsfiddle.net/__pwd__/9fVKH/